# GWT: Servlet URL mapping gives a 404 error

Tags: eclipse, gwt, servlets

I have read the other GWT Servlet questions, but I'm having trouble solving my problem still. My package is called Maps, and it has a service named MyService (which was set up according to a GWT Tutorial). The web.xml file includes the following:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.xerox.maps.maps.server.MyServiceImpl</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServiceImpl</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Maps/service</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In MyService, I have the line:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("service")
public interface MyService extends RemoteService { ...
```

However, when I try to make an RPC call, there is an error thrown. The details of the error say that it is a 404 HTTP error. How can I fix this, to make sure that the mapping is correct?

**Edit 7.27**

MyService.java contains the annotation:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("service")
```

And web.xml contains:

```
<servlet-name>MyServiceImpl</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/com.x.maps.Maps/service</url-pattern>
```

If I follow the XHR with FireBug, it shows me that there is a call to com.x.maps.Maps

Comment: Do you have the link to the tutorial?, I have been coding in GWT lately and may be able to help.(if i see the problem :))

Comment: Sure: I've been using [this one](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html) primarily, as well as [this other tutorial](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideRPCDeployment). Thanks!

Comment: How do you have your entry point set up in the xml file? and are you using rpc.AsyncCallback ?

Comment: I am using rpc.AsyncCallback in my client-side code, but I'm not sure how to set up the entry point in the xml file--where is that in the tutorial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

404 Not found is thrown usually when service endpoint path is inferred wrongly by GWT. Try removing `@RemoteServiceRelativePath("service")` and recompile and check, If that does not work find out the URL endpoint of the service manually (by hitting likely paths from a browser till the error changes to 500 internal error) and then give the correct path as argument to `@RemoteServiceRelativePath("correct/path")`. Few trials I would try right away is `@RemoteServiceRelativePath("/Maps/service")` and `@RemoteServiceRelativePath("Maps/service")` without the slash

Comment: How do I change the path when the code is loading in http://127.0.0.1:8888/Maps.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997?

Comment: Have you tried removing the RemoteServiceRelativePath annotation? And to answer your question, about how to change the path : Use firebug Net panel and go to the XHR section (XmlHttpRequests) and find out first what requests are being made and to which path. Knowing that, cast the object returned by GWT.create() to RemoteServiceProxy and call setServiceEndpoint() method on it, with the correct path or the correct service endpoint

Comment: I did try removing the annotation--should it match the <url-mapping> tag? And I'm not sure what firebug is; I'm using Eclipse. I'm sorry that this is taking me so long to get, but GWT and servlets are very much new to me.

Comment: I'm compiling from Eclipse, and I'm not sure where the Firebug Net panel you're referring to is. I apologize for not knowing more about GWT; my previous coding experience was about as far from servers as one could get.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/ - Firebug is a firefox-addon, and it has the net panel, not eclipse. It tells you exactly what URL/endpoint your service calls hit, and what is the sent data and what is the received response/data. Use it, look at the net panel's XHR tab after enabling it and let me know 2 examples of what URL your service calls are hitting.

Comment: I only get one XHR hit. It's a POST called service, and it's throwing a 404. The Post is:7|0|6|http://127.0.0.1:8888/com.x.maps.maps.Maps/|98544A4AED8C7D42E80C55859E9CEC4C|com.x.maps.maps.client.MyService|readFile|java.lang.String/2004016611|PrinterList.xls|1|2|3|4|1|5|6|

Comment: Unless you made some folder structure changes, the URL pattern is wrong. It should be `/com.x.maps.maps.Maps/` OR `/com.x.maps.maps.Maps/service` instead of `/com.x.maps.Maps/service` - Note the 2 times maps. Im referring to the URL u posted on yur previous comment

Comment: That was it! I wish I could upvote you more than once per answer, but I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

According to this tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC

The servlet-mapping should be composed of the module "rename-to" and the service "RemoteServiceRelativePath". So, if you have, in your *.gwt.xml file, the following line:

```
<module rename-to='XXX'>
```

And in your *Service.java file you have the following line:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("YYY")
```

Then, in your "web.xml" file, you should have the following lines:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>...servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/XXX/YYY</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem but I solved it changing the url-pattern of the Servlet in the web.xml

Try to put in your web.xml the path to the directory where your GWT javascript module is generated, behind WEB-INF/deploy. in my case:

```
<url-pattern>/gwtmodulemain/selection</url-pattern>
```

You can also rename your module name in your gwt.xml file:

```
<module rename-to='gwtmodulemain'>
```

so you can refer your module from your HTML in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="gwtmodulemain/gwtmodulemain.nocache.js"></script>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

New answer after all the comments :

Cool, you have made progress! 
You are hitting this URL -

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/com.x.maps.maps.Maps
```

With this POST data I assume -    `/%7C98544A4AED8C7D42E80C55859E9CEC4C%7Ccom.x.maps.maps.client.MyService%7CreadFile%7Cjava.lang.String/2004016611%7CPrinterList.xls%7C1%7C2%7C3%7C4%7C1%7C5%7C6%7C`

This is where the problem is, your servlet is mapped to respond to XHR requests coming to `<url-pattern>/Maps/service</url-pattern>` but you are hitting `/com.x.maps.maps.Maps` instead. Hence you are getting the 404 path not found status code.

```
Alter the url-pattern on the server-side web.xml to match what the browser is making,
OR
Alter the GWT code using the RemoteServiceRelativePath annotation to make the request to /Maps/service instead of to /com.x.maps.maps.Maps
```

Comment: I'll give this a try tomorrow. Thank you for being really patient with this--I know how tedious it can be

Comment: No worries, configuration is always a headache, until you get it working :)

Comment: Ok, I'm editing my question to show the latest configurations. I tried to edit the url-pattern, but my 404 persists.